# Error when using decision tree in R no observations from which to fit a model

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, na

I was trying to create a tree using this data set and I keep getting the error `no observations from which to fit a model`.I thought this meant that there were too many NA's, but this does not seem like the case. I really want to know what this error means.

The data is amalgamation of various data sets from the world health bank. Here is a picture of how some of it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRiQp.jpg). I know this is hard to reproduce, but I was wondering if anybody had any advice on solving this. I've been looking at it for a while, and haven't made much progress. I added the code below if it helps.

Please let me know if you need any other information, and I will be happy to provide.

Thank you for your time

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(MASS)
library(stringr)
library(tree)

ncol(wbh.2010a)
wbh.2010a <- wbh.2010a[complete.cases(wbh.2010a), ]
sum(is.na(wbh.2010a))
wbh.dat4 <- read.csv('C:/Users/srika/Documents/R/cpts115/HW6/wbh-dat4.csv')
wbh.2010a <- wbh.dat4[wbh.dat4['year'] == 2010,]
fertility.tr <- tree(SP.DYN.TFRT.IN ~ . -country.code - lend.cat - year - income.group, data=wbh.2010a)
```

Comment: I was wondering if this error is caused by having too many NA's, since even after replacing them with the mean, I still get the same error. Mainly I want to know what this error means.

Comment: I removed all of the NA's and it still gives me this error, I don't think its fully because of that. There seems to be certain variables which give the error and ones that do not. I just have no idea why.

Comment: Without a sample (e.g. `head()` of the (imputated, I suppose) data `wbh.2010a`, I doubt anyone can be of any help...

Comment: Its alright I was able to figure it out!